# Keep AVSpeechSynthesizer playing if another view is presented modally

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to utilize the AVSpeechSynthesizer in swift/xcode to read out some text. I have it working for the most part. I have it set so that if they go back to the previous screen or to the next screen, the audio will stop. But in my instance, I want the speech to continue if another view is presented modally.  As an example, I have an exit button that once clicked presents an "Are you sure you want to exit? y/n" type screen, but I want the audio to continue until they click yes and are taken away. I also have another view that can be presented modally, again, wanting the audio to continue if this is the case.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can keep the speech playing when a view is presented modally over top but stop playing when navigating to another view entirely?

Here is my code so far:

```
//Press Play/Pause Button
@IBAction func playPauseButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if(isPlaying){
        //pause
        synthesizer.pauseSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
        playPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
    } else {
        if(synthesizer.isPaused){
            //resume playing
            synthesizer.continueSpeaking()
        } else {
            //start playing
            theUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: audioTextLabel.text!)
            theUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-UK")
            synthesizer.speak(theUtterance)
        }
        playPauseButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
    }
    isPlaying = !isPlaying
}

//Press Stop Button
@IBAction func stopButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if(isPlaying){
        //stop
        synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
        playPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        isPlaying = !isPlaying
    }
}

//Leave Page
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I was able to get the desired functionality. As suggested by Glenn, the correct approach was to get the stopSpeaking to be called in `deinit` instead of `viewWillDisappear`. The issue was that using `AVSpeechSynthesizer`/`AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` normally would create a strong reference to the ViewController and, therefore, deinit would not be called. To solve this I had to create a custom class that inherits from `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` but uses a weak delegate reference to a custom protocol.

The custom class and protocol:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

protocol AudioTextReaderDelegate: AnyObject {
    func speechDidFinish()
}

class AudioTextReader: NSObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    weak var delegate: AudioTextReaderDelegate!
    //^IMPORTANT to use weak so that strong reference isn't created.

    override init(){
        super.init()
        self.synthesizer.delegate = self
    }

    func startSpeaking(_ toRead: String){
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: toRead)
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }

    func resumeSpeaking(){
        synthesizer.continueSpeaking()
    }

    func pauseSpeaking(){
        synthesizer.pauseSpeaking(at: .immediate)
    }

    func stopSpeaking() {
        synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
    }

    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        self.delegate.speechDidFinish()
    }
}
```

And then inheriting and using it in my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class MyClassViewController: UIViewController, AudioTextReaderDelegate{
    var isPlaying = false

    let audioReader = AudioTextReader()

    let toReadText = "This is the text to speak"

    @IBOutlet weak var playPauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.audioReader.delegate = self
    }

    //Press Play/Pause Button
    @IBAction func playPauseButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if(isPlaying){
            //Pause
            audioReader.synthesizer.pauseSpeaking(at: .immediate)
            playPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        } else {
            if(audioReader.synthesizer.isPaused){
                //Resume Playing
                audioReader.resumeSpeaking()
            } else {
                audioReader.startSpeaking(toReadText)
            }
            playPauseButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
        }
        isPlaying = !isPlaying
    }

    //Press Stop Button
    @IBAction func stopButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if(isPlaying){
            //Change Button Text
            playPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
            isPlaying = !isPlaying
        }
        //Stop
        audioReader.stopSpeaking()
    }

    //Finished Reading
    func speechDidFinish() {
        playPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        isPlaying = !isPlaying
    }

    //Leave Page
    deinit {
        audioReader.stopSpeaking()
        playPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        isPlaying = !isPlaying
    }
    @IBAction func NextStopButton(_ sender: Any) {
        audioReader.stopSpeaking()
        playPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        isPlaying = !isPlaying
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future, because this was driving me up the wall.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your `viewWillDisappear`. Any kind of new screen will trigger this, so your code indeed `synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)` will be invoked, thus stopping your audio. And that includes presentation or pushing a new controller.

Now, how to improve that? You've mentioned this:

> I have it set so that if they go back to the previous screen or to the
>   next screen, the audio will stop

First off, **if they go back to the previous screen**:

You'd want to execute the same stopping of audio code line inside your 
`deinit { }` method. That will let you know that your screen or controller is being erased from the memory, meaning the controller is gone in your controller stacks (the user went back to the previous screen). This should work 100% fine as long as you don't have retain cycle count issue.

Next, **to the next screen**, easily, you could include the same code line of stopping your audio inside your function for pushing a new screen.

Comment: From my understanding, deinit does not get called when simply navigating between view controllers, correct? If my user hits the Back button to return to the previous screen (or progresses to the next screen), deinit is not called, but viewWillDisappear is.

Comment: Yes. Trust me on this. So far this is the easiest thing I could suggest to you to do. `deinit` is invoked when the controller gets deallocated, that includes a screen/controller from being POPPED or DISMISSED. :) https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Deinitialization.html As for the latter part of your comment, the deinit should be called, read my answer again for the reason why your deinit isn't being called when pressing the back button. Try a simple project, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm being a bit thick. I have carefully reread your answer, but I don't understand how to utilize deinit with uinavigation (back) if it doesn't get called from those types of interactions.

Comment: You don't call the deinit directly. The system invokes that. You can read the doc, and like I said, you can make a very simple 2-screen iOS project, with push and pop, with the second screen having a deinit function, and don't put break points in deinit, just put print("deinit").

Comment: I must have a reference keeping the deinit from being called on my viewcontrollers class. I read through the documentation and understand what it's saying, but deinit is never called.

Comment: Yes, there must be a retain cycle issue in your controller or any class you're referencing from that controller, or any block that you're not using weak self with. Anyhow, my answer should answer your question, after you solve your new problem. :) If there's any other answer that actually answers your question or help you, don't forget to select that as an answer. Good luck! Post a new, separate question if needed for your new problem.

Comment: So I think I've tracked down the problem to my view controller class inheriting AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate itself, and that is causing the strong reference that is preventing deenit ```class ClassThatNeedsToSpeak: UIViewController, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {``` I think if i were able to set the AVSpeechSynthesizer's delegate declaration to weak, it would solve my issue, but I don't know how to go about that

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions, I was able to dig around and find exactly what I had to do. I'm going to post it as a separate answer so that if anyone else needs to do something similar, they'll be able to implement it.